# Email delays issues in VPS server on GoDaddy Server

Tags: php, email, godaddy, smtp

We're working on a web service, and our registration confirmation emails are constantly delayed almost 5-10 mins on GoDaddy's servers.

We've tried PHP's `mail()` function and also the PHPMailer SMTP library, but are experiencing delays with both.

We want to receive emails immediately. Can anyone guide us?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately e-mail delays and other issues like this are common with GoDaddy - and as far as I'm aware, using an SMTP library to an *external* SMTP server won't work at all as GoDaddy will block it.

The best you can do is contact GoDaddy support and ask if there is a problem on the server you are on, but I'd hazard a guess that there's not going to be much resolution you can get from that.

I'm sorry it's not what you want to hear, but unfortunately in the end, the only thing you can really do is change hosts. A 5 - 10 minute delay on e-mails is excellent compared to the e-mails problems that do often occur with GoDaddy.

Comment: i have already contact to  GoDaddy support but they told me that you have vps we cannot access to your account. you have to check mail log on your server.but am new and i have no idea that how can i check it ?

Comment: @Gorakh That's a different question.... I'm surprised GoDaddy won't help you, according to https://godaddy.com/pro/managed-vps they offer support on their VPS plans too, even the self-managed ones. As for how to check the mail log it's going to differ depending on your server set up so you might need to ask whoever manages your hosting for you, or do some Googling and ask on ServerFault if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> We've tried PHP's mail() function and also the PHPMailer SMTP library, but are experiencing delays with both.
>
> We're working on a web service, and our registration confirmation emails are constantly delayed almost 5-10 mins on GoDaddy's servers.

First, determine if any of the third-party software is the culprit. Maybe your PHP script runs slowly to the point where it takes 5 minutes before the `mail()` function completes.

Try sending mail a couple of times using the most basic fully functional email client on the server and see how long it takes. If the time is roughly 5 minutes each time, then you may need to restart or reconfigure the email processing software (exim?) on the server. I found that when I run into this situation, and reconfigured the mail server (so no errors exist or appeared in the logs), the mail was being processed quickly again.

> We want to receive emails immediately.

Depending on how far the email travels, I'd suggest waiting at least 1 to 2 seconds each time your server sends mail to a client before claiming that it is sent.